# Applescript to add images in table cell in textedit file

Tags: macos, applescript, textedit

I'm new to mac development. I want to add images in the table cells in textedit file through applescript.I dont have any idea how to do it.

tell application "TextEdit"
    open file "Users:developer:desktop:test.rtfd"
end tell

Can anyone help me.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
I dont have any idea how to do it.
```

Every application has their own applescript commands. You have to look at the applescript dictionary for an application to find what it can do. As such your first action should be to look at TextEdit's dictionary and see if there are any commands for what you want to do. To do that open AppleScript editor. Under the File menu choose "Open Dictionary" and select TextEdit. You can browse the dictionary or use the search field. This is where you should start.

I don't know how to do what you want either but I'd start at the dictionary and then use google too. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you aren't putting everything on one line in your script, then I think the reason it's not working is that the full path name should include the name of the hard drive.

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    open "Name of hard drive:Users:developer:desktop:test.rtfd"
end tell
```